# Compare time using Laravel and MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In a Laravel application I have some columns that are of type `time` (NOT `datetime`) in my MySQL database. I am casting these time columns in my model using Carbon like so:

```
public function getStartDateAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $this->attributes['start_time]);
}
```

The issue is that Carbon automatically sets any unspecified fields (e.g. month, day, year) to the current date.

This creates an issue when comparing times.

For example, say we have a model called `Foo`, with 2 records:

- `id: 10`, has a `start_time` of `5:00am`
- `id: 30`, has a `start_time` of `3:00am`

And the following code:

```
 // Date and time the code was executed is 25/11/2016
 $a = Foo::first('id', 10)->start_date; // Fetched at 11:59pm
 // ... some delay ...
 $b = Foo::first('id', 30)->start_date; // Fetched at 00:00am (date is now 26/11/2016)
 dump($a->gte($b)); // where $a and $b are carbon objects
```

Usually the last statement will almost always return true because 5:00am is later than 3:00am.

However, because `$a` was fetched at 11:59pm and `$b` was fetched at 00:00am, then no matter what the value of 'start_date' is, the statement will ALWAYS return false!

It's a rare corner case I know, but this is how things get hacked.

Therefore my question is, what is the proper way with dealing and comparing time for the MySQL time column?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the php [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function like so:

In your model:

```
public function getStartTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return strtotime($value);
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
$a = Foo::first('id', 10)->start_time; // Fetched at 11:59pm
$b = Foo::first('id', 30)->start_time; // Fetched at 00:00am
dump($a <= $b); // evaluates to false
```

Comment: I initially up-voted this, but it has the exact same issue. If today's date is `1/2/2017`, and I did this at `11:59`: `strtotime('10:43:12)` I will get a timestamp for `1/2/2017 10:42:12`. Now if it just turned `2/2/2017` and I did the same function again, I will get a timestamp for `2/22017 10:42:12`. Therefore the comparisons will be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your example compare - `23:59pm` with `00:00`. You expect 00:00 to be greater than 23:59.

So as you are aware, 00:00 could be either before or after 23:59 as the clock is continuous, but without the `date` component, mysql / php / any language will assume that it is on the same day. As such, 23:59 will always be before 00:00.

As such, your expectation of how your code should behave is wrong unless you provide date information.

Further, if you change `00:00` to mean the following day, then you will have a bug when 00:00 actually means the same day.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I have a MYSQL time column. This does not have any date. Therefore 23:59pm should be greater than 00:00am. However, when casting a time into Carbon, it unfortunately also includes the day, month and year. This would not be an issue if it was all set to the same date, but is a huge issue if there was a change in the dates. I'll edit my question to clarify!

Comment: Also my example does not compare 23:59pm or 00:00am. This is when the data was fetched. I edited my question to make this more clear